# Select from drop down list or enter a new one - Designing

Tags: usability, web-app, input-fields, drop-down-list, choices

I am developing a website that allows users to create line-ups for sport matches.  I want to help users to save a line-up for a particular team for the next match too by saving them to the user's favorites list. If the user has one or more saved teams on his favorites list it will appears one drop down meny on start.

[image]

Now I'm quite unsure about the best solution for UX design.

1. When the user chooses one team from the list should the team name fill the text box below or should the text box below be disabled?
2. If the user chooses one team from the list how to leave him the possibility to enter a new team if he changes his mind?
3. Does anyone have a better design solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Auto-complete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) instead - best of both worlds! That way, you don't have two UI elements, only one - and you can still standardise people's data entry.